# Continuity of function $f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } (cos(x-\pi/4))^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

How to check continuity of such function?
For me it will be continuous for $x \neq \pi/4+n\pi$ because for such x $|(cos(x-\pi/4))|<1$
But I'm not sure. Can someone tell me if I'm wrong or not? Thanks

Comment: Have you figured out at what points $x$ the sequence converges?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check if is well defined the function.

What happen with $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi + 2k\pi$? You would have $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n$. Then for this $x$ $f$ can't be continous.

For any $x \neq \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi + k\pi$ $f(x)=0$ and for points near to $x$ the function is also $0$ therefore the function is continous for that kind of points.

For $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi + 2k\pi$ $f(x)=1$  the function is not continous because for any point near $x$ the function is $0$ therefore cannot be continous for that points.